# Como hacer una consulta WHERE NOT EXIST luego de un INSERT en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo problemas con la siguiente consulta:

```
INSERT INTO `pasajeros` ( `nombre`,`apellidos`,`email`,`password`,`telefono`)
VALUES ('Alexandra','Gonzalez','cesa@cesar3.com','1234567!','04242344556' )
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `transportistas` WHERE `email` = 'cesa@cesar3.com');
```

Que tengo mal en el código? Necesito hacer un Insert solo si el correo no esta usado en esa otra tabla. Simplemente agregue la sentencia de `WHERE NOT EXISTS` a un lado pero al parecer no cumplo con la sintaxis requerida, como puedo mejorar mi código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para poder usar el `where not exists`, se necesita un `select`. De modo que necesitas convertir la claúsula `values` a un `select`:

```
INSERT INTO `pasajeros` ( `nombre`,`apellidos`,`email`,`password`,`telefono`)
SELECT 'Alexandra','Gonzalez','cesa@cesar3.com','1234567!','04242344556'
  FROM dual
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `transportistas` WHERE `email` = 'cesa@cesar3.com');
```

Otra manera, siguiendo el mismo principio, un poco más complicado, pero que evita que repitas el valor para el correo electrónico en 2 lugares, es usando una tabla derivada:

```
INSERT INTO `pasajeros` ( `nombre`,`apellidos`,`email`,`password`,`telefono`)
SELECT i.nombre, i.apellidos, i.email, i.password, i.telefono
  FROM (SELECT 'Alexandra' as nombre,
               'Gonzalez' as apellidos,
               'cesa@cesar3.com' as email,
               '1234567!' as password,
               '04242344556' as telefono) i
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `transportistas` t WHERE t.`email` = i.email);
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra idea podria ser con una condición de esta manera:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
    (   SELECT  1
        FROM    `transportistas`
        WHERE   `email`= 'cesa@cesar3.com'
    )
    BEGIN
        INSERT `pasajeros`(`nombre`,`apellidos`,`email`,`password`,`telefono`) 
        VALUES ('Alexandra','Gonzalez','cesa@cesar3.com','1234567!','04242344556') 
    END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer también con `JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO `pasajeros` 
          (`nombre`,`apellidos`,`email`,`password`,`telefono`)
   SELECT 'Alexandra','Gonzalez',temp.email,'1234567!','04242344556'
           FROM (SELECT 'cesa@cesar3.com' AS email) temp
           LEFT JOIN transportistas ON transportistas.email = temp.email
           WHERE transportistas.email IS NULL
```

Se crea una tabla temporal con el valor del email y se compara con la columna email de transportistas, si ES NULO, se hace la inserción porque dicho email no existe en transportistas.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, hice mis labores de investigador y he encontrado una manera en la que podría llegar a lograr su cometido, ojalá le sirva. Saludos

```
INSERT INTO `pasajeros`(`nombre`,`apellidos`,`email`,`password`,`telefono`)
SELECT 'cesa@cesar3.com'
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `email` FROM `pasajeros` WHERE `email` = 'cesa@cesar3.com')LIMIT 1
```